# Java awt Swing - Did I encounter a Bug?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have no run-time error but the problem is obvious.

When I code **g.drawString ("message",45,45);** it outputs this when I run the program. If you cannot see basically the window 'prt screened' my current screen with the g.drawString in the correct position.

NOTE: method paint over-rides *java.awt.Window.paint*

[image]

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class test extends JFrame{

 public test (){

         setSize(800, 600);
         setVisible(true); 
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setTitle("PlotGraph");
    }
     public void paint(Graphics g){

         g.drawString("Click the mouse inside the window.",40,45); // draw a string
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new test();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, where did you expect the text to be if not at coordinates (40, 45) ? Measuring from the top-left of the window (including the title bar and stuff), that looks like coordinate 40, 45 to me.

Comment: Oh, I was confused by you red-marking the text. The problem is what is **outside** the text. I understand now.

Comment: Well,I am too getting the same problem...here..

Comment: When i minimize and reopen the window i get a black background applet.Do you also get the same @BDillan??

Comment: @JohnSnow yes. And Simon your not making it better :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the statement

```
super.paint(g);
```

the window uses the background as a temporary background for the window. This will paint the background as well as all child components of the container.

In Swing [paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) is used rather than `paint` for custom painting.

Comment: @BDillan No, it's  a bad idea to delete questions if they are answered and not downvoted. Questions stick around to educate future users, as well as the asker.

Comment: Adtually, part of the responsibility of paintComponent is to to clear/prepare the graphics context for painting. If you fail to honour the paint chain, what ever was painted last to the graphics context will be left there. The graphics context is a shared resource, anything painted before you will remain to be painted if you don't allow it to be cleared. This is especially true for transparent components as it will screw up what's painted below them - FYI